# $p$-subgroups and Sylow $p$-subgroups

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

In several proofs and exercises I have read is used the fact that if one is given that $H$ is a $p$-subgroup of $G$, then $H$ is a subgroup of a Sylow $p$-subgroup. Whenever I ask, I am told that this is as a consequence of Sylow Theorems (I think that the second one). Why is this a consequence if the theorem just claims that all Sylow $p$-subgroups are conjugate? There cannot be a $p$-subgroup that isn't contained in any Sylow $p$-subgroup?

Comment: Often something stronger is proved than just "all Sylow $p$-subgroups are conjugate" - instead many sources prove "all $p$-subgroups can be conjugated to lie in any Sylow $p$-subgroup". For example this is what Wikipedia proves [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorems#Proof_of_the_Sylow_theorems) and the [proof of (ii) here](https://dec41.user.srcf.net/h/IB_L/groups_rings_and_modules/1_7). This is what these proofs are quoting.

Comment: Please provide *context*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $P$ be an arbitrary $p$-subgroup of $G$ and let $S$ be a Sylow $p$-subgroup. Then $P$ acts on $G/S$ by left-multiplication. This is a $p$-group acting on a set of order prime to $P$, so there is a fixed point, say $gS$.

Since the sets $PgS$ and $gS$ are the same, we have $P \subset gSg^{-1}$. But $gSg^{-1}$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup.

Comment: (And yes, some people say this is Sylow's second theorem and others say the statement that all Sylow $p$-subgroups are conjugate is the second theorem. This statement is more useful but harder to summarize.)

Answer (score 3):

In addition a fun fact (stated without proof but with hints): if $P$ is a $p$-subgroup of $G$, then $\#\{S \in Syl_p(G): P \subseteq S\} \equiv 1$ mod $p$.

Hints: $P$ acts by conjugation on the set of Sylow $p$-subgroups; use $P \subseteq S$ if and only if $P \subseteq N_G(S)$ (here you need the statement that you were after in the first place (applied in $N_G(S)$)); use the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups is $\equiv 1$ mod $p$; apply the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem.